# python LightGBM reproductibility issue

Tags: python, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I am running a lightGBM on a classification problem, with crossvalidation (using sklearn) to get the optimal hyper parameters values.

Although I specified the random_state when create the model object, rerunning the grid search results in different optimal parameters each time.

```
import lightgbm as lab
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

lgb_estimator = lgb.LGBMClassifier(boosting_type='gbdt',
                                  objective='multiclass',
                                  num_class= 4,
                                  random_state = 42,
                                  )
grid = {
    'num_leaves': [60, 70, 80, 100, 120],
    'feature_fraction': [0.5, 0.7],
    'bagging_fraction': [0.7, 0.8],
    'num_trees':[50, 80, 100],
    'C': [0, 0.3, 0.5, 1]
}

GBM_grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = lgb_estimator,
                     param_grid = grid,
                     scoring = 'f1_micro',
                     cv = 15,
                     n_jobs = 2)


lgb_model_trained = GBM_grid_search.fit(X=X_train, 
                        y=y_train)
```

My training data is splitted using a random seed so no issues on that side

What's causing the randomness ? And how to solve this ?

Comment: are you running your LGBM code on different machines? or you are doing it on the same compiler?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, setting the random seed (random_state in LGBMClassifier) does not result in reproducibility if LightGBM is working in parallel (n_jobs>1). If you need reproducibility and want to use all your n cores, you should find or create a method to run n instances of LightGBM with n_jobs=1 each. The simplest way: having 2 cores you may run 2 instances of your original code, the first one with bagging_fraction=0.7, the second one with bagging_fraction=0.8, each one with n_jobs=1. Or simply set n_jobs=1 without any other changes, if reproducibility is more important than speed.